# How do I output content at the right point from a WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress plugin for a specific site, which needs to read a feed from another site and display the contents (nicely parsed).  The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to display the resulting HTML.

I have the following:

Main file (feed-import.php):

```
/*
Plugin Name: etc
*/

class FeedImport {

    private $feedData  = "";
    private $jsonData;

    public function __construct(){  
        // hook shortcode
        add_shortcode('myshortcodename' , array(&$this , 'shortcodeExecute')); 
    }

    // Read shortcode params
    public function shortcodeExecute($atts , $content = ""){

        if(!class_exists('ParseJSON')) {
            require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'class-parse-json.php';
        }

        // Get feed data
        $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://feedurl.com' );

        if(isset($response['body']) && !empty($response['body'])) {
            $this->feedData = $response['body'];
        }

        // Decode feed data
        $this->jsonData =  json_decode($this->feedData);

        // Parse feed data
        $parseJSONObject = new ParseJSON($this->jsonData);
        $output          = $parseJSONObject->buildHTML();

    }

    function getOutput() {

        return $this->output;
    }

}

$feedImport = new FeedImport();

function add_the_feed ( $content ) {
    if ( is_page() ) {
        return $content . '<p>html content goes here.</p>';
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_the_feed');
```

class-parse-json.php:

```
class ParseJSON {

    private $jsondata = "";

    public function __construct($jsonData) {

        $this->jsondata = $jsonData;

    }


    public function buildHTML(){

        $html = "<div>";

        foreach($this->jsondata as $key => $value) {
            $html .= "<div>";
            $html .= "  <a href='" . $value->html_url . "'>";
            $html .= $value->name;
            $html .= "</a>";
            $html .= " </div>";
        }

        $html .= "</div>";

        return $html;

    }

}
```

(I've left out details of error checking etc for clarity).

This works fine - it adds the text 'html content goes here.' at the end of each page.  What I can't figure out is how to replace 'html content goes here' with the actual html content - ie the value of `output`.

I tried changing add_the_feed to:

```
function add_the_feed ( $content ) {
    if ( is_page() ) {
        return $content . $feedImport->getOutput();
    }
}
```

but then I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: feedImport
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This might be a scope issue, try including `$feedImport = new FeedImport();` inside of your `add_the_feed` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variable scope issue. The `add_the_feed()` function does not have access to the `$feedImport` variable. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Include `$feedImport = new FeedImport()` in your function.
2. Use a singleton and create a static instance method (outlined below)

   ```
   class FeedImport {  

       /* New Lines */
       protected static $_instance = NULL;


       public static function instance() {
           if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
               self::$_instance = new self();
           }

           return self::$_instance;
       }
       /* End New Lines */


       public function __construct() { 

       }

       // Read shortcode params
       public static function shortcodeExecute($atts = '' , $content = '' ){

           if(!class_exists('ParseJSON')) {
               require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'class-parse-json.php';
           }

           // Get feed data
           $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://feedurl.com' );

           if(isset($response['body']) && !empty($response['body'])) {
               $feedData = $response['body'];
           }

           // Decode feed data
           $jsonData =  json_decode($feedData);

           // Parse feed data
           $parseJSONObject = new ParseJSON($jsonData);
           // Return the data in the shortcode.
           return $parseJSONObject->buildHTML();

       }
   }

   // put the short code out of the Class
   add_shortcode('myshortcodename' , array( 'FeedImport', 'shortcodeExecute'));
   ```

Comment: Thank you!  I think it's almost working, but I'm now getting "Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context", referring to the line return $this->output;

Comment: Ah, because your original code doesn't actually have an `output` method or property. I've updated my answer. Basically, instead of `$output = $parseJSON...`, I created a private `$output` property at the top of the Class and assigned the `$parseJSON...` value to that property, then we can call it later using `$this->output`

Comment: Thanks, but that hasn't made any difference - I'm still getting the same error, again referring to the same line.

Comment: Whoops! Yeah, I see the error. Updated the code. What changed is the scope of `getOutput()` (no longer static), in the return of `add_the_feed` I updated how to access the method of `FeedImport()->getOutput`

Comment: That's working now!  Thank for all your help, it's made things much clearer!

Comment: Ok, it's not quite working... no errors, but the value of output being returned is empty.  If I do a var_dump after the buildHTML line, output is populated, but the value returned from getOutput is empty... any ideas?

Comment: So, after looking at this, the main reason this isn't working for you, is that at no point in `function getOutput()` are you calling `shortcodeExecute()`. So, essentially, you will get a blank `$output`. I've updated the answer to move some things around. Move the `add_shortcode` out of the class and execute the `shortcodeExecute()` in the `_construct()`.

Comment: Update: I kept the `add_shortcode` in the `_construct`

Comment: If I put '$this->shortcodeExecute();' in the '_construct()' it executes on every page... I only want it to show up on pages where I have the shortcode.

Comment: Again, are using the shortcode? In your original question, you are trying to access the `getOutput` method and append it to `the_content`. If you are actually using `[myshortcodename]` in your editor, I'll update the answer. And according to your code, it will execute on every page - your `add_the_feed` function is running on every page.

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm putting [myshortcodename] only on the page where I want it to appear.

Comment: So you don't actually need the `add_the_feed()` function at all. Is that correct?

Comment: If I don't put add_the_feed() in, nothing outputs at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199862/discussion-between-disinfor-and-sharon).